# R calling a dataset in the package itself

Tags: r, package, dataset, packaging

I have created a package containing a dataset called `mydata`.

I want to use my dataset in my functions but I dont know how to call it.
when i use `data("mydata")` to call my dataset and avoid warning messages I have another message during the building process

> See section ‘Good practice’ in ‘?data’.

`@imporFrom mypackage mydata` doesn't work either. What's the best way to call a dataset in the package itself?

Answer (score 7):

Use `package_name::mydata`, example in `car` package `car::Angell`.

Dataset is in a `data` folder with for example `mydata.rda` inside.

To add help, create a `data.R` file in `R` folder.

Personnaly I put inside :

```
# 1. mydata ----

#' Here is a long title
#'
#' Description of the dataset : length, columns
#'
#' @format one object of class XXX
#'
#' @source where it comes from
#' @name mydata
NULL
```

Comment: @thierrycnam you have two arrows up and down on the left of each answer and accept button on the center